# Rails 5 is ignoring view templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails project, I ran:

```
rails generate scaffold car
```

which successfully created all of the necessary files and directories for the application. This includes the standard `application.html.erb` layout file, as well as the app/views/cars directory that includes more standard `html.erb` files (index, show, ETC.)

In addition, my cars route is in place in `config/routes.rb`.

My next command is rails server, which is also successful.
When I open my browser and go to `localhost:3000`, the welcome page for ruby on rails pops up as normal. I'm expecting that when I go to `localhost:3000/cars`, I'll see the html rendered from `app/views/cars/index.html.erb`. If not, I at least expect that it will default to `application.html.erb`.

Instead, I am repeatedly receiving the following:

```
>ActionController::UnknownFormat in CarsController#index
>CarsController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []
```

My controller class looks like this:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_car, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  #  GET /cars
  #  GET /cars.json

  def index
    @cars = Car.all
  end

  #  GET /cars/1
  #  GET /cars/1.json

  def show
  end

  # GET /cars/new

  def new
    @car = Car.new
  end

  # GET /cars/1/edit

  def edit
  end

  # POST /cars
  # POST /cars.json

  def create
    @car = Car.new(car_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @car.save
        format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @car }

      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /cars/1
  # PATCH/PUT /cars/1.json

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @car.update(car_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @car }

      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /cars/1
  # DELETE /cars/1.json

  def destroy
    @car.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cars_url, notice: 'Car was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

  def set_car
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.

  def car_params
    params.fetch(:car, {})
  end
end
```

I'd greatly appreciate any insight into this issue. I've followed every bit of advice I've seen on the internet regarding layouts, controllers, and views, and I'm having no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your index action look like?

Comment: Forgive me if this is not what you're asking, I'm new to Rails. The index method in the controller says: @cars = car.all. This is the only line in index as of now.

Comment: Is the 'c' in `car.all` lowercase?

Comment: I wrote it that way, but it's actually uppercase in the code.

Comment: Please post your cars controller. Likely an issue with the format and render block.

Comment: Controller code is included in the original post now, thanks!

Comment: Remove everything from the index action and see what happens.

Comment: Same result unfortunately.

Comment: First remove all the scaffold with `rails d scaffold car` and then re-create with `rails g scaffold Car` - note it's Capital `C` now in `Car`. Try this.

Comment: Still getting the same error. Thank you.

Comment: what is the path to your index.html path, and also post routes.rb

Comment: in you routes.rb file, set root 'cars#index'

Comment: What does your car index view look like?

Comment: Are you perhaps using Rails in API mode?

Comment: Can you add you route file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who was trying to answer my question! It was a stumper, but I've discovered the problem:

After uninstalling and reinstalling rails a few times, I created a dummy rails project and generated a new scaffold "car." Upon running rails server and loading up localhost:3000/cars, the default layout was rendered as normal. Thinking that reinstalling rails had solved it, I then linked the dummy project to a remote github repository.

At this point, running rails server and loading localhost:3000/cars showed me the same error message as before. This made me believe that something about the remote repo was messing up my project, so I googled around for this error message and github.

I stumbled upon the following link which ultimately answered my question:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18660

Turns out, one of the directories in my root path was capitalized, and that was throwing rails off right away. As soon as I renamed the capitalized directory to all lowercase, the app ran flawlessly.

I'm frustrated by ruby on rails' extremely opinionated conventions, and especially since this project is almost a week late due to such an esoteric mistake. But I'm over the moon to have it running smoothly now and I hope this may help someone else in the future.
Thanks again all!